# How to Show 30 days in Day View with Horizontal Scrollbar in Dhtmlx Scheduler?

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I want to show 30 days in Day View Scheduler with Horizontal Scrollbar. Currently, Horizontal Scrollbar is [available](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html#horizontalscroll) only for Timeline View but I want it for Day View as well as Month View.

For Timeline View with Horizontal Scrollbar code:

```
scheduler.createTimelineView({
name: "timeline",
x_unit: "minute",
x_date: "%H:%i",
x_step: 30,
x_size: 24*7,
x_start: 16,
x_length: 48,
y_unit: sections,
y_property: "section_id",
render: "bar",
scrollable: true,  
column_width: 70, 
scroll_position:new Date(2018, 0, 15)   });
```

Please share your ideas and Sample links

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Custom View`](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_views.html). You can remove the default `Day` view and display your own instead, with the number of days you want to display. This can be done like this:

First in [`scheduler.config.header`](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_header_config.html) set tab "thirty_days" instead of "day":

```
   scheduler.config.header = [
       "thirty_days",
       "week",
       "month",
       "date",
       "prev",
       "today",
       "next"
   ];
```

The label for the view is set as in:

```
   scheduler.locale.labels.thirty_days_tab = "Days";
```

Next, set the start date of the viewing interval, as well as viewing templates. It's better to create the custom view in the [`onTemplatesReady`](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_ontemplatesready_event.html) event handler function so that your custom view templates are ready before the scheduler is initialized:

```
   scheduler.attachEvent("onTemplatesReady", () => {
       scheduler.date.thirty_days_start = function(date) {
           const ndate = new Date(date.valueOf());
           ndate.setDate(Math.floor(date.getDate()/10)*10+1);
           return this.date_part(ndate);
       }
 
       scheduler.date.add_thirty_days = function(date,inc) {
           return scheduler.date.add(date,inc*30,"day");
       }
 
       const format = scheduler.date.date_to_str(scheduler.config.month_day);
 
       scheduler.templates.thirty_days_date = scheduler.templates.week_date;
 
       scheduler.templates.thirty_days_scale_date = function(date) {
           return format(date);
       };
   });
```

To add horizontal scrolling to the view, you can place the scheduler inside the scrollable element and give the scheduler the width required to display all columns. You'll need to hide a default navigation panel of the scheduler and create a custom one with HTML, so it would have a correct width and won't be affected by scrolling:

```
   scheduler.xy.nav_height = 0;
 
   scheduler.attachEvent("onSchedulerReady", function () {
       const navBar = scheduler.$container.querySelector(".dhx_cal_navline").cloneNode(true);
       navBar.style.width = "100%";
       document.querySelector(".custom-scheduler-header").appendChild(navBar);
 
       document.querySelectorAll(".custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_tab").forEach(function (tab) {
           tab.onclick = function () {
               const name = tab.getAttribute("name");
               const view = name.substr(0, name.length - 4);
               scheduler.setCurrentView(null, view);
           };
       });
 
       document.querySelector(".custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_prev_button").onclick = function () {
           const state = scheduler.getState();
           scheduler.setCurrentView(scheduler.date.add(state.date, -1, state.mode));
       };
 
       document.querySelector(".custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_next_button").onclick = function () {
           const state = scheduler.getState();
           scheduler.setCurrentView(scheduler.date.add(state.date, 1, state.mode));
       };
 
       document.querySelector(".custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_today_button").onclick = function () {
           scheduler.setCurrentView(new Date());
       };
 
       scheduler.attachEvent("onBeforeViewChange", (oldView, oldDate, newView, newDate) => {
           const innerContainer = document.getElementById("scheduler_here");
 
           if (newView === "thirty_days") {
               innerContainer.style.width = "3000px";
           } else {
               innerContainer.style.width = "100%";
           }
 
           return true;
       });
 
       scheduler.attachEvent("onViewChange", function (view, date) {
           const dateLabel = document.querySelector(".custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_date");
           const state = scheduler.getState();
           dateLabel.innerHTML = scheduler.templates[view + "_date"](state.min_date, state.max_date);
 
           document.querySelectorAll(".custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_tab").forEach(function(tab) {
               tab.classList.remove("active");
           });
 
           const activeTab = document.querySelector(".custom-scheduler-header ." + view + "_tab");
 
           if (activeTab) {
               activeTab.classList.add("active");
           }
       });
   });
```

Styles that you will need:

```
   .custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_navline{
       display: block !important;
       height: 60px !important;
   }
 
   .custom-scheduler-header .dhx_cal_navline.dhx_cal_navline_flex{
       display: flex !important;
   }
 
   .dhx-scheduler {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto, Arial;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
 
    .dhx_cal_container .dhx_cal_navline {
       display: none;
    }
```

Please see an example: https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/znd7ffiv

You may need to fix the hour scale so that it remains visible when scrolling horizontally on the calendar. I did not implement this in the example, I think that this can be done in the same way as for the navigation panel. If you need, write to me and I will send an update in a few working days.

As for the "Month" view, the approach is the same as for the "Day" view.